# calculating a frequency band around the mode in pandas/numpy

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, bokeh

I have a pandas series of value_counts for a data set.  I would like to plot the data with a color band (I'm using bokeh, but calculating the data band is the important part):

I hesitate to use the word standard deviation since all the references I use calculate that based on the mean value, and I specifically want to use the mode as the center.

So, basically, I'm looking for a way in pandas to start at the mode and return a new series that of value counts that includes 68.2% of the sum of the value_counts.  If I had this series:

```
val  count
1    0
2    0
3    3
4    1
5    2
6    5    <-- mode
7    4  
8    3    
9    2   
10   1

total = sum(count) # example value 21
band1_count = 21 * 0.682 # example value ~ 14.3
```

This is the order they would be added based on an algorithm that walks the value count on each side of the mode and includes the higher of the two until the sum of the counts is > than 14.3.

```
band1_values = [6, 7, 8, 5, 9]
```

Here are the steps:

```
val  count   step
1    0
2    0
3    3
4    1
5    2    <-- 4) add to list -- eq (9,2), closer to (6,5)
6    5    <-- 1) add to list -- mode
7    4    <-- 2) add to list -- gt (5,2)
8    3    <-- 3) add to list -- gt (5,2)
9    2    <-- 5) add to list -- gt (4,1), stop since sum of counts > 14.3
10   1
```

Is there a native way to do this calculation in pandas or numpy? If there is a formal name for this study, I would appreciate knowing what it's called.

Comment: 1-Why do you choose `(val,count)=(5, 2)` for the fourth choice in your list over `(3, 3)`?, 2-How do you decide who goes first between `(3, 3)` and `(8, 3)`?

Comment: I've updated the question with a walkthrough of how to compare and select values above and below the mode.